# How To exclude a specific list of number at a specific position

Tags: excel, numbers, position

I have a list of numbers and I would like to remove every numbers that are different that the number I want to keep for eg that's the list:

```
01 54 88  <== remove
09 52 55  <== remove 
08 55 67
00 66 22  <== remove
04 44 11  <== remove
04 52 74  <== remove
02 98 65  <== remove
05 55 33
```

So here I remove every number different than "55" at position 4
So I keep:

```
08 55 67
05 55 33
```

these two numbers

Is it possible to do that with Excel ?

*Note: I have an KuTools for Excel if necessary.*

Thanks for help in advance and sorry for my english :)

Comment: And what is the criteria for removing a number?

Comment: The criteria is if the number "55" is at the position 4 like the example below they are remove

note: i made a mistake i'm so sorry now it's better

Comment: what does this look like in the sheet? Can you show some data in the sheet? E.g. is 01 in one column or 01 54 88 in one column? And are you counting a space as a position?

Comment: 01 54 88 is one column sorry here is the example : https://i.imgur.com/CHJXTsN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple filter with

```
text equals:  ???55???
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Yup.  Could also select then copy the visible rows; or use the Advanced Filter and filter to another location.

Comment: yes thanks it looks great but is it possible to add more filter like "equals" ???55??? AND ???56??? AND ???57??? I mean more than 2

Comment: @Exceler You can use the Advanced Filter for that.  Look at HELP for general advice and also, in particular, using `Multiple criteria, one column, any criteria true`, and also `wild card criteria` The Advanced filter has an advantage in that you can set it to place the results elsewhere.

Comment: @Exceler In conceptualizing your mulitple filters, you should be connecting them with `OR`'s.  Otherwise it will always evaluate to `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Keep55Rows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim targetArray()
Dim targetRange As Range

Set targetRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

targetArray = targetRange.Value2

Dim outputArray
ReDim outputArray(1 To UBound(targetArray, 1), 1 To UBound(targetArray, 2))

Dim rowCount As Long
Dim currentRow  As Long
Dim currentColumn As Long

For currentRow = LBound(targetArray, 1) To UBound(targetArray, 1)

    If InStr(1, CStr(targetArray(currentRow, 1)), "55") = 4 Then

        rowCount = rowCount + 1

        outputArray(rowCount, 1) = targetArray(currentRow, 1)

    End If

Next currentRow

outputArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArray)

ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To rowCount)

outputArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArray)

With targetRange
    .Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Resize(UBound(outputArray, 1), UBound(outputArray, 2)) = outputArray
End With

End Sub
```

Assumes contiguous range from cell A1 in named sheet but easy to adjust to range of interest. Simply modify `targetRange` and `ws` variables.

[image: Example input output]